# DELL INSPIRON 7559 - UBUNTU 16.04(DUAL BOOT) Reboot/Shutdown/Suspend Error

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, inspiron

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Win 10 in my new inspiron 7559(Core i5 6300HQ, 8 GB RAM, Nvidia GTX 960M 4GB DDR5). I am having a few problems.

1. Shutdown freezes occasionally. I get error message saying - "Soft bug: CPU freeze for 22s"
2. Restart and suspend never work....it just hangs with a black screen and i have to long press power button to shutdown.
3. Backlit Keyboard light automatically turn regularly. This happens both in windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04( Errors 1 and 2 are present only in ubuntu)

NOTE:
I didnt change any boot parameters while installing. I just turned off fast shutdown and secure boot and then installed ubuntu normally using a USB drive.

Please help me resolve my errors

Comment: The question is too broad. First thing to check is Nvidia drivers. Did you install them?

Comment: Seems like Nvidia Drivers were installed during OS installation itself. Still i tried installing Nvidia drivers                                                                (1.sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
2.apt-get update
3.sudo apt-get install nvidia-364)                                                                                        after this and a single reboot ubuntu crashed

Comment: Why 364? The official ones are 361. The latest in PPA are 367.

Comment: Ok can u please tell me what exactly i should do now? Should i try installing 367?

Comment: I would suggest to remove the ppa and try the stable drivers first. But I am not sure that it is related to your problem.

Comment: i have removed ppa 364 .... ok i'll try installing 361 if that's what u mean b y stable drivers..thanks a lot!!

Comment: You need to purge the PPA first. Otherwise you will install the driver from the same PPA.

Comment: I have the same problem and I have reported bugs but no body cares. It should be the nvidia driver problem, but none of the drivers work. By which I mean I cannot even boot the system.

Comment: @dspjm I reinstalled ubuntu 16.04, but this time i did both system updates and 3rd party driver updates. After that i opened additional drivers folder where i found Nvidia 361.25 driver. But ubuntu was using nouveau driver. I changed this setting to Nvidia driver and now shutdown and restart seems to work fine( I tried 6-7 times and i'm not getting soft-bug-CPU-stuck error). Hope this helps you!

Comment: @ShivramGowtham thanks for helpbing. But I cannot find the 361.25. The oldest for 16.04 is 361.42, while there is a 361.28 build for 15.10, I just cannot find 361.25

Comment: @ShivramGowtham BTW, the latest 370 never fix the problem as well. Cannot see this will be fixed in the near future I think.